# How can I return instancetype in Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift

I want to make an extension of some class to return the runtime type object

for example, I create extenstion of class A

```
extension A {
    class func niceObject() -> XXXXX { // in objective-c is instancetype
        return ....
    }
}
```

So anyone know there is instancetype keyword in Swift or not to replace `xxxxx` and I can call this function on subclass of A without manually cast

```
var b: B = B.niceObject()
```

Thanks

Comment: Have a look at this page from the Swift Programming Language resources, particularly "Downcasting": https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/swift_programming_language/TypeCasting.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH22-XID_446

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You can do it. Playground code below. It's self() that niceObject() has to return. Additionally, you must have a `required` init on the base class.

```
class A {
    required init() {
    }

    func whatClassAmI() -> String {
        return "Class A"
    }
}

class B: A {
    required init() {
        super.init()
    } 
    override func whatClassAmI() -> String {
        return "Class B"
    }
}

let a = A()
let sa = a.whatClassAmI() // "Class A", of course

let b = B()
let sb = b.whatClassAmI() // "Class B", of course

extension A {
    class func niceObject() -> Self {
        return self.init()
    }
}

let aa = A.niceObject()
let saa = aa.whatClassAmI() // "Class A"

let bb = B.niceObject()
let sbb = bb.whatClassAmI() // "Class B", as required
```

Comment: In my personal case, i have to do the same with
`extension A {
    class func niceObject() -> [Self] {
        // do stuffs
        return MyArrayOfSelf
    }
}`</br>
It do not work, unfortunately

Comment: doesn't dynamicType support this https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Types.html so if all you have are Base Class references it works

Answer (score 23):

There is a keyword `Self` which is allowed in two places - in protocols (see Jean-Philippe Pellet's answer) and as a result of `class` methods:

```
extension A {
    class func niceObject() -> Self? {
        return nil
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, this won't help you because the following is invalid

```
extension A {
     class func niceObject() -> Self? {
         //A can't be converted to Self
         return A()
     }
 }
```

The error is caused by the fact that when you inherit from `A`

```
class B : A {
}
```

then

```
var b = B.niceObject()
```

would actually return an `A` instance which is not convertible to `Self` (`Self` is `B`)

@Grimxn found the correct solution ([See his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24182819/669586)):

You have to add a required initializer to the base class, e.g.

```
class A {
   @required init() {
   } 
}
```

and then you can call the initialiser using `self()`

```
extension A {
     class func niceObject() -> Self {
         return self.init()
     }
 }
```

Comment: I think the error you mention is not because of run ```B.niceObject()```. It is compile-error. Seems like we cannot use Self in extension unless we can return object type Self

Comment: @ZoonNooz I tried to explain why we can't return a `Self` in Swift. Although it would help if we could access `Self` as a Type in that method.

Comment: I got what you mean now. BTW in my situation in objc, I query NSManagedObject in coredata base on current type. so I can return it as a NSManagedObject and it will be subclass type when I call function. But not in swift.

Answer (score 10):

At least in procotols, you can use `Self`. This represents the actual type of `self`. Not sure about extensions, though...

For instance, see the definition of `Equatable`:

```
protocol Equatable {
    func ==(lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Bool
}
```

Comment: notice that if you are doing an `extension` for a `Dictionary` for example and want to return the same type of `Dictionary`
you would have to do `extension Dictionary {

 func changeSomeThing() -> Dictionary {
  return self
 }
}`

Answer (score 0):

When you use a Swift API from Objective-C, the compiler typically performs a direct translation. For example, the Swift API `func playSong(name: String)` is imported as `- (void)playSong:(NSString *)name` in Objective-C.

However, there is one exception: When you use a [Swift initializer](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithObjective-CAPIs.html) in Objective-C, the compiler adds the text “`initWith`” to the beginning of the method and properly capitalizes the first character in the original initializer.

For example, this Swift initializer `init (songName: String, artist: String)` is imported as `- (instancetype)initWithSongName:(NSString *)songName artist:(NSString *)artist` in Objective-C.