# Swift protocol defining class method returning self

Tags: swift, protocols

I had code that was working in XCode 6 beta but stopped working recently after updating to xcode 6.1.

This is my protocol:

```
protocol CanDeserialiseFromJson {
    class func FromJson(json : JSONValue) -> Self
}
```

This is implementation:

```
extension Invoice : CanDeserialiseFromJson {
    class func FromJson(json : JSONValue) -> Self {
        return Invoice()
    }
}
```

This fails giving error:

```
'Invoice' is not convertable to 'Self'
```

As I said, this used to work and I can't work out why it doesn't anymore

Comment: Compare http://stackoverflow.com/a/24182819/1187415.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25645090/protocol-func-returning-self/25645689#25645689

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Self` in a protocol is a requirement that implementations of the protocol use their own type. Since `Invoice` is the type you're adopting the protocol in, your implementation of `FromJson` should have a return type of `Invoice`.

Comment: Which it does: return Invoice()

Comment: He means the return type should be `Invoice` :)

Comment: Then it would not conform to protocol: Method 'FromJson' in non-final class 'Invoice' must return `Self` to conform to protocol 'CanDeserialiseFromJson'

Comment: I marked Invoice class as final and it seems to work

Comment: What should I do if I don't want to mark it as `final`?

Comment: @KleinMioke see my answer bellow. I had the same issue.
Also discussed at more length here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24181556/343155

Answer (score 4):

It's right. Your method is declared to return `Self`, whereas you are returning `Invoice`. Class methods are inherited, and in subclasses, `Self` will be that subclass type, and `Invoice` is not a subtype of that type.

To actually return `Self`, assuming `Invoice` has a `required init()` constructor, you can do something like this:

```
extension Invoice : CanDeserialiseFromJson {
    class func FromJson(json : JSONValue) -> Self {
        return self()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you really need to return Self (in my case I have an Objective-C protocol that translates a method into swift function returning Self) and not mark your class as final, you need to create a required initializer and use that:

```
class Foo {
    static func bar() -> Self {
        return self.init()
    }

    required init() {

    }
}
```

The final/required requirement comes from the fact that you might subclass this class and have a different initialiser.
Final removes the option for a subclass, while the required init makes sure that any subclass will implement the required initialiser used in the static method.